# How to access a member from an App class in a page from a WinUI3 project

Tags: c#, winui-3

The structure of a blank WinUI 3 application is:

```
MainWindow
 - App
   - FirstPage
```

What is the correct way to use an object in the `FirstPage` class which was declared in the `App` class? How would I access it? One way would be to declare the member as static for the `App` class.

Comment: App (derives from Application) should be the top  in your structure. There's only one Application that can containy many Windows. The app is accessible using Application.Current (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.application.current?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4). You can cast it to your own class and access your members this way.

Comment: Application.Current is the most obvious method, but it's not easily testable due to the hard dependency between the FirstPage class and the App class.

Another way is to use dependency injection. If FirstPage is part of a navigation frame, then you can only have a constructor with no parameters due to the fact that WinUI will instantiate the page and can only do so through the no=parameter constructor.

Comment: In such case, you can use the DI service provider to get the instance of the object you need. If you are using MVVM, then that whole thing is part of the View Model which you can, and will, instantiate on your own and can inject into its constructor at will. 

Attaching the ViewModel to the FirstPage can be done in many ways as usual, in the constructor of the page or later when the page is loaded, etc...